# How can I convert a timestamp INT into a Date format?

Tags: opa

Hello I'm trying to convert an INT timestamp in to an OPA Date format !

I would have checked on the opalang API documentation, but it is not available at the moment.

Is there a solution ?

```
timestamp_to_int(thetimestamp:int) = (
    Date.date(thetimestamp)
  )
```

that doesn't works !

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem with:

```
Date.milliseconds(myTimestamp)
```

May have seen the answer if the documentation was available :/